# JQuery Datatables - Search - Remove Dom Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I have jquery datable with pagination and search active.

The first column  hold a checkbox, from a list of items.

Some of these items are already checked (coming from database)

When I do the search, the jQDatatables, remove the dom elements and some of 'checked' itens are not showing

- Ok until here.

The problem is, when I submit the form with checked values and filter is 'active', the others checked values are not sending to post. - because they are not on dom table- only the filtered.

There is a way to jqDt, not remove the dom element when filtering, just put a 'hidden' class on tr element?

Regards

Comment: This question really needs to be backed up by some code, showing what you actually are doing.

Comment: your codes please...

Comment: here is code - http://jsfiddle.net/am5djkyc/3/ - as you see, record 1 is checked, if you filter for '2', and check then, when you submit, only record 2 is send.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to your table definition and first column will never be searched again

```
"aoColumns": [
    { "bSearchable": false, "bSortable": false },
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null
]
```